# Setup Eclipse for BlackBerry development

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I want to start blackberry development. From the BlackBerry site I found that Eclipse is good for development. Since I have previous experience with Eclipse I decided to go with it. Now my problem is that I am not able to download the Eclipse plugin for BlackBerry.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Eclipse are you using? I recommend [Eclipse Galileo 3.5](http://www.eclipse.org/galileo/) for BB development.

Once installed, click help > Install new software > and add the following website to work with:

```
http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java
```

This should give you a list of the available JRE versions for BB development, select a version depending on the OS of the device you want to develop for, 5.0 is the most common at the moment.

Click next and go through the steps, you will be asked to log in eventually, use your credentials from the BB development website and register at the "[Register for access to the BlackBerry Developer Zone](https://www.blackberry.com/bdsc/?lang=na#register)" page.

You should be good to go from there! Remember when making a new project to select new > other > blackberry project. Also remember to set the JRE to the Blackberry JRE you downloaded if it's not done automatically.

Comment: don't we need the eclipse plug in for development..??

Comment: Yes but thats what your doing when you follow the first step above e.g. Help > Install new Software etc.

Comment: No actually sorry I gave you the wrong link, the link quoted above is to download Eclipse Galileo! Sorry I'll edit the post now.

Answer (score 2):

(as posted elsewhere on this site: [BlackberryPreprocessBuilder and BlackberrryResourceBuilder Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10993285/383414) - to link these questions, and add extra FYI info to this thread)

My recommendation is to use this latest download of [Eclipse & the plugin](http://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=96FC862494C97799CC07421E57F1FDAB&check1=A).

BlackBerry tools are not very good, so I find it best to use a dedicated Eclipse, only for BB dev. I have found that this download is working well for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be a member of 'BlackBerry developer zone'.

Technical requirements:

- Eclipse 3.6 Helios
- 32-bit Windows® XP, Windows Vista® or Windows 7 (Note: 64-bit versions require 32-bit Java and Eclipse)
- Monitor with a resolution of 1024 x 768 or higher
  PC with Intel® Pentium® 4 processor or compatible (2.5 GHz or higher, 2 GB RAM, 1.5 GB HD free)
- Java® SE Development Kit (JDK) 6, update 10 or later

You'll get more information at [http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp]

You can download simulators from [http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp]