# BlackberryPreprocessBuilder and BlackberrryResourceBuilder Missing

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I am using Blackberry eclipse java plugin 1.5
I am not getting BB development environment.
[Preprocessor directives supported by the RIM compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179129/preprocessor-directives-supported-by-the-rim-compiler/1189573#1189573)
and [Using preprocessor directives in BlackBerry JDE plugin for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383277/using-preprocessor-directives-in-blackberry-jde-plugin-for-eclipse)
I used those links but not working..
Plaese help

Comment: the links work - add details to the question please

Comment: I am getting simply java development environment. I am not getting Blackberry development environment.In properties->Builders->Missing BlackberryPreprocessBuilder Missing BlackberrryResourceBuilder

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to use this latest download of [Eclipse & the plugin](http://swdownloads.blackberry.com/Downloads/contactFormPreload.do?code=DC727151E5D55DDE1E950767CF861CA5&dl=96FC862494C97799CC07421E57F1FDAB&check1=A).

BlackBerry tools are not very good, so I find it best to use a dedicated Eclipse, only for BB dev. I have found that this download is working well for me.

Install this version - I think it will fix all your problems. If not, reply and I'll see if I can help further.